# How to create dynamic horizontal layout in pure HTML/CSS no JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Take a look at this example:
http://jsbin.com/ixiju4/2/edit

I have a **wrapper** which height is defined and two containers inside: **top** and **bottom**.
The height of the top container **isn't** fixed (in the example it is set to 100px but this is just for demonstration). What I want is to dynamically set the bottom container to fill the rest of the wrapper.

In this demonstration I did it using JS:

```
$(function() {
  var top = $('#top');
  var bottom = $('#bottom');
  bottom.height(bottom.parent().height()-top.outerHeight());
});
```

Do you think there is a way to do it in pure HTML/CSS? No matter how, I can even use **tables**. I've been thinking about the solution for some time now and haven't found any cross browser compatible one.
Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE 1:**
I've made one mistake defining this questions **top** has no fixed height - it is defined by it's content.
http://jsbin.com/ixiju4/6

**UPDATE 2:**
OK. This is what I really want:
http://jsbin.com/ixiju4/8

Comment: Following your update I'm still confident that the underneath solution will work. If you want, you could set a min-height CSS property to at least keep a space in the event that something goes wrong with your dynamic content generation :)

Answer (score 9):

There's a pretty easy pure CSS solution to this:

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #top {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f4f7;

  }
   #bottom {
    background-color: #00f400;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
  }
```

**UPDATE 2** Following on from your last round of editing to the question, I've updated the CSS accordingly, which is:

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #top {
    background-color: #00f4f7;   
  }

  #bottom {
    background-color: #00f400;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  #inner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f400;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: If you put an overflow: hidden on #wrapper it is even nicer.

Comment: Hehehe, thanks - I wish I had moments of clarity like this all the time :)

Comment: I doubt this solution makes sense:
http://jsbin.com/ixiju4/11
#bottom would be 100% height of the #wrapper and it must be #wrapper.height - #top.height

Comment: Based on the question you asked, it worked perfectly. The comment you made above, however, seems to indicate the criteria is changed. Perhaps rephrase what you want the HTML/CSS to do - you've edited the question several times over, only saying "this is what you want".

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can use tables:

```
<table style="height:400px">
  <tr>
    <td style="height:100px">Fixed to arbitrary value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:auto">Dynamically filling</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsbin.com/ixiju4/3

**Disclaimer:** Dear Googler, if you found this answer: Don't do this at home! Tables for styling are evil. Use `display: table` and `display: table-row` to achieve the same effect in everything but IE < 8

**Edit 2:** OK, for completeness:

```
#wrapper { display: table; }

#top, #bottom { display: table-row; }
```

Doesn't work in IE < 8, as mentioned. http://jsbin.com/ixiju4/5

**Edit 3:** I was really blind. Yes, Tiny Giant Studios answered with the obvious way to do it. You should go with his answer. (I'm leaving mine for completeness.)

Comment: Please, please, please: avoid at all costs using tables for layouts - tables are for tabular data, and that's it. Also, using the `style` attribute - that's no good, either.

Comment: @jgradim: Cool down. The OP seems to be in urgent need, says explicitly that he is fine to use tables for styling and you can't provide a better solution (CSS3 grid doesn't count), as far as I can see.

Comment: My appeal was not a critique to the answer - instead, an appeal to the author. Sorry if misunterstood :)

Comment: OK, then we are on common ground. The only excuses I can think of for tables for styling are email templates and intranet apps for IE6 with a tight deadline.